# how to previous data and database backup to restore new SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

[how to previous data and database(SQL Server Version 8.00.0194) backup to restore new SQL Server (SQL Server Version 14.00.1000)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA5Kg.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need SQL 2008 R2 SP4. This is the last version of SQL Server that supports SQL 2000 databases. Once you restore your database, you will need to back it up again, and then restore in SQL 2017. See [SQL Server 2017 supported versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2017?view=sql-server-2017)

Unfortunately Microsoft makes it hard getting SQL Server 2008 Developer edition. I suggest you contact Microsoft representatives.

You can download Express [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=1695) but it will not be able to restore large databases.

Alternatively you can use Azure to create a VM that has SQL 2008 R2 pre-installed. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-iaas-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json)